# htacces redirects infinite loop

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have moved all content of website from root into a sub-folder. Old links coming from external website is now therefore broken and goes directly to my `404` which redirects to front page.

```
https://www.website.com/content.html  -->  https://www.website.com/subfolder/content.html
```

I have tried adding this to my htacces without succes. It ended up in an infinite loop adding "subfolder/" to the url.

```
RewriteRule ^$ subfolder [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1 [NC,L]
```

My complete redirect:

```
#Rewrite everything to https
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^$ subfolder [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1 [NC,L]
```

How can I redirect the content to the sub-folder?

Comment: Like them all. Internal links also get redirected into infinite loop.

Comment: Test in Chrome dev tool with **caching disabled** and check in Networking tab what are 301/302 redirect URLs you get.

Comment: I just tested. I couldn't recreate the problem with the infinite loop but all CSS, scripts etc got 404 (Not found). These are not in the `/subfolder/` but in another folder in the same root.

Comment: What is correct path of CSS and what is 404 URI of CSS